# Java - How to store a variable via main method in a different class?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm supposed to store variables of an object based on user input inside a main method, to a different class. I'm getting static to non-static reference errors for "gerbil.id" and "gerbil.name"; I don't even know if it would save to the variables in the object in the gerbil class. Any ideas? Here's what I have so far:

**EDIT: Now I get a nullpointerexceptor when I run with the fixes posted; here is the updated code. the exception points to the gerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next() line specifically. I'm not sure what could've caused it. I've listed id as a string and also input a string (one word) when run.**

**Inside of my *information* class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many gerbils in the lab?");
    int numberOfGerbils = keyboard.nextInt();
    Gerbil[] gerbilArray = new Gerbil[numberOfGerbils];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfGerbils; i++){

        System.out.print("Lab ID:");
        gerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next();

}
```

**Inside of the *gerbil* class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gerbil {

public String id;


public Gerbil(String name) {
    this.id = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: inside the loop, it should be `Gerbil[i].id = keyboard.next();`

Comment: That still keeps the static to non-static reference error :\

Comment: in which line you are getting the error?

Comment: I now have a nullpointer accepter when I try to run it. Any way of fixing that?

Comment: -1 given your question is specifically (in your words) " How to store a variable via main method in a different class?"  surely there is no need for showing that program, just some lines to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Barlop I was showing him an updated piece of my code because of an error. But I've cut down the code.

Comment: @newJavaUser where exactly you are getting the exception? show us the stacktrace.

Comment: @maxx777 the exception points to the `gerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next()` line specifically. I'm not sure what could've caused it. I've listed `id` as a string and also input a string (one word) when run.

Comment: check the corrected code. does the exceptin is thrown in the first iteration itself?

Comment: With the corrected code, the exception is thrown in on the first iteration around. On the first inquiry for the ID, I type the id, and then I get a `java.lang.nullPointerException` pointed at the `gerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next() line`. I've tried switching `next()` to `nextLine()` but same error, just happens before I've input the ID with the `nextLine()` code.

Comment: that was because the default constructor was not provided implicitely. check the edit. it's working on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many gerbils in the lab?");
    int numberOfGerbils = keyboard.nextInt();
    Gerbil[] GerbilArray = new Gerbil[numberOfGerbils]; // initialization of array

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfGerbils; i++){
        GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil();
        System.out.print("Lab ID:");
        // String Gerbil.id = keyboard.next(); should be replaced by
        GerbilArray[i].id=keyboard.next(); // because you should call non static members using objects of a class. Here object is an array element which requires an array index.

        System.out.print("Gerbil Nickname:");
        //String name = keyboard.next(); replace by
        GerbilArray[i].name=keyboard.next();
        // as stated earlier. and you don't need to write String again because you have already declared it in the class declaration. If you try to do this way, you are creating a new String object only. This name has already been assigned to array, so it will result in an error.
    }
}
```

in the Gerbil class, contructor should be corrected as

```
public Gerbil(String name, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}
```

because local members hides class members. here `name` and `id` of constructor will hide name and id of class. the above statements does nothing. it is an assignment made to itself only. `this` keyword is used to point to invoking object.

and since you are providing a parameterized constructor, but you are creating objects using default constructor, you need to explicitely create a default constructor as well.

```
Gerbil(){}
```

Comment: I have a nullpointerexceptor error when I try to type in the labID when running the program.

Comment: i have edited my answer. it was because of incorrect array name. check if it runs now.

Comment: and as a good practice, you should follow the language naming conventions.

Comment: Still has the same nullpointerexception error. I reuploaded my code to show you. And thanks on the naming conventions, I hadn't caught that.

Comment: @newJavaUser caugth another error, in the for loop it should be `<` instead of `<=`. remember that array index starts from 0. For `n` objects, array indeces are form `0` to `n-1`

Comment: The only problem was that I forgot one specific piece of code to create the new "gerbil." Such a stupid mistake and it took me 20 minutes of looking to actually find it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
GerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next();
```

instead of

```
Gerbil.id = keyboard.next();
```

It would help to avoid this kind of confusion if you followed the convention of starting variable names with lowercase letters. So then it would be:

```
gerbilArray[i].id = keyboard.next();
```

Comment: agree with the naming convention part.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException as there is a problem in allocating the space for the array. For example:
numberofGerbils=5  then
***gerbilArray[0],gerbilArray[1],gerbilArray[2],gerbilArray[3],gerbilArray[4] are created***.

But as you are trying to access the gerbilArray[5], it is showing NullPointerException.
You have used ***"i<=numberofGerbils"***. it *should not be "<="*. It should be **"<"** only. This will solve the problem.As when you are using "=", the array index 5 is called, which actually does not exists!!!

Comment: That change doesn't affect the NullPointerException. I'm getting the exception at the first iteration, when saving the ID at gerbilArray[0].